# Recent drop in Tor clients?

Tags: relays

Today I looked at the Tor Metrics for the first time. I was surprised by the data on the number of direct users. It appears that the number of users has recently decreased by 50% in the past month. Below is a screenshot from [Tor Metrics](https://metrics.torproject.org/userstats-relay-country.html?graph=userstats-relay-country&start=2014-04-19&end=2015-11-17&country=all&events=off). Does anyone know what's causing this? This was my first time looking at Tor Metrics, so perhaps it's caused by delays in data gathering? Just curious.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with Tor metrics that shouldn't occur anymore. What happened was that partial data for a given date was included in the graph generation. When you look at the metrics website now, the issue is gone.